# How to stop Text To Speech in C# in a GUI

Tags: c#

I made a GUI which can get user text and read it aloud. But once it started speaking, it won't stop when I try to(I want to stop the the speaking when the button is clicked again).

Example:
When the text of the button == "Speak" it will read, when the text of the button == "Stop" it must stop speaking.
(Here I'm using only one button).
And the button is freezing also.

Here is my code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace TalkBack
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SpeechSynthesizer spe = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void talk(string text)
        {
            spe.Speak(text);
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btn.Text != "Stop")
            {
                btn.Text = "Stop";
                string data = inputbox.Text;
                talk(data);
                btn.Text = "Speak";
            }
            else if (btn.Text != "Speak")
            {
                btn.Text = "Speak";
                spe.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help..

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/354

Comment: why are you setting it to speak in both cases?  Maybe it's not freezing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the synchronous speak call in a Task:

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btn.Text == "Speak")
    {
        btn.Text = "Stop";
        string data = inputbox.Text;
        await Task.Run(() => {
                spe.Speak(data);
            });             
        btn.Text = "Speak";
    }
    else // It must say "Stop" right now:
    {
        btn.Text = "Speak";
        spe.StopSpeakingAsync();
    }
}
```

*This is totally UN-TESTED!....

Comment: When I used 'StopSpeakingAsync();' code won't run and says 'SpeechSynthesizer does not contain a definition for  StopSpeakingAsync and no accessible extension method StopSpeakingAsync accepting a first argument of type SpeechSynthesizer could be found' what should I do to this error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.8.1): rather than calling `Speak(text)`, use [`SpeakAsync(text)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasync?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-speech-synthesis-speechsynthesizer-speakasync(system-string)) to start the speech, and then call [`SpeakAsyncCancelAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasynccancelall?view=netframework-4.8.1)  to stop the speech.

```
spe.SpeakStarted += (_, _) => btn.Text = "Stop";
spe.SpeakCompleted += (_, _) => btn.Text = "Start";

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btn.Text != "Stop")
    {
        string data = inputbox.Text;
        spe.SpeakAsync(data);
    }
    else if (btn.Text != "Speak")
    {
        spe.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
    }
}
```